# Redirecting GET Requests with parameter to PUT/DELETE Types

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rest

I have a RESTful API which accepts all of the standard verbs, including PUT and DELETE, however most web browsers don't support PUT and DELETE in their native FORMs.

Is it possible to use my existing .htaccess to rewrite a GET request with a specific variable (&METHOD=PUT) to use the PUT verb so that my code is not required to work around this limitation in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to do that using rewrite as rewrite engines are for rewriting URLs while to convert request types(GET to POST for example) one needs to change message header/body.